# JavaScript does not correctly detect elements on the page

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, console.log

The given code does not work, I do not know why, when instead of adding to the query variable I write console.log this console displays values and then returns an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

```js
let editProduct = (id) => {
    let length = sessionStorage.getItem("valuesArray").length;
    let query = "UPDATE `products` SET id='"+id+"', ";
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll("label")[i].innerHTML);
    }
    alert(query);
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you closer:

```
const editProduct = id => {
    const length = sessionStorage.getItem("valuesArray").length;
    let query = "UPDATE `products` SET id='"+id+"', ";
    // querySelectorAll returns a NodeList. Convert to Array:
    const labels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("label"))
    const labelsText = labels.map(label => label.innerHTML)
    console.log(labels.join(', '))
    alert(query);
}
```

The issue with your code is that you are iterating using the length of the array you get from localstorage, but there is no guarantee that the length of that array is the same as the number of label elements on the page, and it appears that there are more items in the array than label elements.

You should iterate over the collection returned by `document.querySelectorAll("label")` instead.

I recommend you learn `Array.map` and `Array.filter`. They are safer and easier to reason about than loops.

Your intent is not clear in your code, but if you want to "get a number of label elements equal to `Math.min(labels.length, valuesArray.length)`", then you want to do something like:

```
const editProduct = id => {
    const length = sessionStorage.getItem("valuesArray").length;
    let query = "UPDATE `products` SET id='"+id+"', ";
    const labels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("label")) || [];

    const numberOfElementsToGet = Math.min(labels.length, length) - 1;
    const elementsToGet = labels.slice(0, numberOfElementsToGet)
    const labelsText = elementsToGet.map(label => label.innerHTML)

    console.log(labels.join(', '))
    alert(query);
}
```

Comment: The code does not work, and the value of sessionStorage is certainly equal to the length of inputs and labels.

Comment: When you say "it does not work", do you get an undefined error with my code?

Comment: returns "Uncaught TypeError: labels.slice is not a function" on line 7

Comment: See, now with that I can do something. Updated. I'll add a comment explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the valuesArray it is any array or not to apply the length function to put a correct end to the loop

```
   let length = sessionStorage.getItem("valuesArray").length
```